# WEKA - Create Instances from a List of feature Vectors in Java

Tags: java, vector, weka, svm

I have a large List of feature Vectors with fixed lengths. The List is 1000 Vectors long and Vector length is of 10.000 double values each.
100 vectors represent one class (100 samples per class) so later model training will involve this logic: 100 positive samples against 900 negative samples or in  short, one class against all other.

**How can I create Instances in Java from a List of Vectors to do some model  training?**

This is my List that holds all the feature vectors:

```
public static List <Vector<Double>> featuresList = new LinkedList<Vector<Double>>();
```

Please let me know if I left anything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To train your model you have to create an `instances` to decelerate your attributes.
Instances is a set of `instance`s. Then you can add your instances to your instances.
From a double vector you can create a SparseInstance or DenseInstance:

```
public SparseInstance(double weight, double[] attValues)

public DenseInstance(double weight,  /*@non_null@*/ double[]attValues){
```

May be instead of `Vector<Double>` you can use a double array.

You can find any useful information to create instances at https://weka.wikispaces.com/Programmatic+Use

Comment: I've already checked out the Weka Intro. page a few times before but I haven't seen `SparseInstance`s in use there, only `DenseInstance`s and `FastVector`s. FastVectors are deprecated as far as my knowledge goes here, so the info. there is not so recent anymore. Care to share a bit more info on `SparseInstance`s usage? What does Instance weight describe? I'm new to Weka so every info. will help a lot. I have already completed parsing vectors to arrays (no problem there). Thank You.

Comment: You can create a DenseInstance also from a double Vector. Sparse instance is similar to dense instance (or your dense double vector), but data with value 0 are not be explicitly represented.
e.g. dense format:

    0, X, 0, Y, "class A"
    0, 0, W, 0, "class B"
and the sparse format:

    {1 X, 3 Y, 4 "class A"}
    {2 W, 4 "class B"}
you can find more info at https://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+(stable+version)#Sparse ARFF files

Comment: Instance weight is good e.g. when your training set is unbalanced, e.g. the negative instances (or one class when you try classify instances) are overrepresented. In this case you can overweight your positive instances (or rare classes) to help your ML model to learn. But, mainly you only set to 1.0.

Comment: Thank You again for your answers. if I understood correctly, I can create any of the two Instances (dense or sparse) and setting weights to Instances will actually serve like giving them "more negative" or "more positive" properties. For an example, setting weights for all my positives to {5.0} and negatives to {1.0} will say positives are very distant from all negatives. Please correct me if I misunderstood that.

Comment: Yes, I think you understood well. :)

Comment: Giving you a thumbs up for your effort. Thanks again!